# TimestampBehavior is not working in Yii2

Tags: yii2

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],

        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['create', 'update', 'delete', 'view', 'index'],
            'rules' => [
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                // everything else is denied by default
            ],
        ],

        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['create_time', 'update_time'],
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['update_time'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Above code is for my controller behavior function. While creating or updating, 'create_time' and 'update_time' fields are not getting updated by current time. Type of those fields are set to datetime. Please need your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare it in the behaviors method of your model.

> To use TimestampBehavior, insert the following code to your ActiveRecord class

```
public function behaviors()
{
  return [
    'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
        'attributes' => [
           ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['create_time', 'update_time'],
           ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['update_time'],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: I have this same issue. I have the behaviors in the model class. They seem to work but the times are always set to epoch ("0000-00-00 00:00:00") every time

Comment: This is because your columns are DATETIME type in your database. Change it to INTEGER(11) and it will work ;)

Comment: Mine is set to TIMESTAMP, but also sets as `0000-00-00 00:00:00:00`. Setting to `INT(11)` just sets it to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works for me:

```
use yii\db\Expression;
...

        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'update_time',
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
```

Comment: But I think this will only work for MySQL. Any other RDBMS may flag an error. This is something the developers of Yii2 should take into consideration.

Comment: Time and time again WHY do people use int fields to store timestamps its SUCH a bad idea.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan why not ? it is unix time so you can convert it to readable date time ez. Plus it works with timezone

Comment: Manipulating SQL dat fields in SQL is faster, there are many native ways to manipulate SQL date fields in PHP, Using libraries such as Carbon consume SQL date formats by default.

Comment: SQL timestamps, implicitly stores data in GMT time zone. No matter what your session time-zone is. Useful if you need to use different timezones.

Comment: You can have automated timestamping columns using DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (one column per table only until MySQL 5.6.5)

Comment: You can use datetime function for date comparision, addition, substraction, range lookup etc, without the need to use FROM_UNIXTIME() function - it will make it easier to write queries that can use indexes

Comment: You can still retrieve integer unix timestamp with no additional overhead using UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
 'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

if you would like to use the PHP datetime.

Answer (score 1):

I used `new Expression('NOW()')` to store current timestamp. But It does't store the date based on current timezone. Instead it stores based on server time.

I just used normal php date function to solve this.

eg :

```
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\Expression;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
            ],
            'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must also add the value and use the class Expression

```
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\Expression;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
            ],
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```