# I'm facing this error when trying to setup my wordpress on my local machine, but failed with error

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress

I'm trying to setup a copy of my wordpress in my local server, the wordpress was customised with nodeJS and some other vendor's packages. when setup and trying to run the wordpress, i received this error:

Error: The configuration for the "log" component must contain a "__class" element.

Which i think something related to Yii2 framework, i have changed the version from 2.0.6 to 2.0.14 in the composer.json file, but no luck. Anyone can help?

Server is ubuntu server 18.04, running nginx and mysql, with PHP 7.2.

Comment: did you try to change yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6" to "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14" ?

Comment: I did, no luck.

Comment: Can you post the code from the components, especially the "log" part?

Comment: which file should i look for?

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/15895) issue, You need to modify the log key like this

```
'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
        'class' => 'yii\log\Logger',
    ],
```

**EDITS**: The error you are receiving now, has something to do with TimeStamp. So, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27515600/733889) answer,

> You have to declare it in the behaviors method of your model. To use TimestampBehavior, insert the following code to your ActiveRecord class

```
public function behaviors()
{

return [
'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
    'attributes' => [
       ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['create_time', 'update_time'],
       ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['update_time'],
],];
}
```

Comment: I got it, thanks. But now have different error.

Error: Call to undefined method yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className()

Comment: create another question so we can help you. It seems like we are in a x,y problems situation